# How can I draw a graph from an external file using R markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to use R markdown. I've got the R code for my graph in an external file and I would like to draw the graph in R markdown file using `source` or `read_chunk` to read my R code. I was unable to find a solution by myself.

Here is my [gist](https://gist.github.com/pachevalier/9132601), copied below for convenience:

gr.R

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
```

Markdown document:

`````
```{r data, echo=FALSE}
library("ggplot2")
library("knitr")
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), u = rnorm(100))
df$y <- 1 + df$x + df$u
```


```{r test, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
read_chunk('gr.R')
```

```{r test2, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
source('gr.R')
````
`````

Comment: Do you have a file called `gr.R` in the same folder as your RMarkdown document?  If so, your code should work with `source()`.

Comment: I've got gr.R in the same folder but it doesn't work.

Comment: To be more precise, if I choose `echo=TRUE` in the `source` function, I've got the source code + the graph but I'm don't know how I can have the graph without the source code in the output

Answer (score 2):

You will need to explicitly print the plot:

gr.R

```
plt <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
```

rmarkdown

`````
```{r test2, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
source('gr.R')
print(plt)
````
`````